# Desktop-like application in ExtJS 4

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, firebug, extjs4.1

I develop some application with "desktop", shortcuts and widget on it. So, I have a lot of AJAX requests when open my application.

They freeze each other, and Firebug shows that response time was about 170-250 ms, but in nginx log all responses have time about 50-60 ms.

How can I to fix it? Need I to build some queue, or some workaround with Web Workers, etc.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix is to switch from low level Ajax to Ext.Direct remoting. One of its advantages is request batching, it's built in and automatic. Why not use it?
See the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/direct_grid_pt1

Answer (score 0):

What I have personally played around with is, for inital page load, have 1 ajax call that does the whole lot, and then when that loads, either have a store factory, or figure out which data you loaded, then manually publish that to the store.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){   
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'page.php',
        params: {
            id: 1
        },
        success: function(response){
            var text = response.responseText;
            var json = Ext.JSON.decode(text);

            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore')
            store.add(json.myStore.records);
            // and do for whatever other stores you need to do

        }
    });
})
```